# Check which C-Lightning version I am running?

Tags: core-lightning

Ive downloaded and unpacked the new version 0.6 but is there anyway I can check through CLI commands which version i'm running to ensure the update worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just use:

```
$ lightning-cli --version
v0.6-127-gf8fa421
```

Comment: Notice that the first part (`v0.6`) shows the latest release this version is built on, followed by the number of patches applied on top (`127`) and then the git commit that was built (prefix `g`, commit `f8fa421`). This allows us to pinpoint exactly which commit you have built.